# How to import auth.User on django-import/export

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-import-export

I can't import a CSV file into model on Django.
I made a column 'author' and put the superuser's id which I am login to the admin site.
But there was an error like this when I import the CSV file.

```
Line number: 1 - null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (10, abc, blahblah, null, ).
5, abc, blahblah, , nah,wha,blah
```

**csv file**

```
author,title,text,file,free_tags
5,abc,blahblah,,"nah,wha,blah"
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class KnowHow(models.Model):    

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to='explicit_knowhows')
    free_tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources
from import_export import fields
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

from .models import KnowHow
# Register your models here.

class KnowHowResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = KnowHow
        exclude = 'id'
        import_id_fields = ('title', )

@admin.register(KnowHow)
class knowHowAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = KnowHowResource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed when I saved the CSV by encoding in UTF-8. This will not support non-alphabet letter so I recommend using .xlsx file instead. 
Thank you to everyone who tried to fix my problem.

Comment: I also noticed that I can't import Django taggit. I will ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `author_id` is missed.

Django [adds a postfix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) to all the `ForeignKey` fields, so you should try to modify the file renaming the column:

```
author_id,title,text,file,free_tags
5,abc,blahblah,,"nah,wha,blah"
```

Comment: Maybe add the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) to the documentation to improve the answer.

Comment: I did it but unfortunately, nothing changed.```author_id,category,title,text,file,basic_tag,free_tags
5,abc,blahblah,,"nah,cmon,blah"```

Comment: Yeah. ```Line number: 1 - null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL``` I also tried "author" column's value to the username, but nothing changed either.